# gupnp-av-cp fails to set volume of Sony Bravia on LAN through wi-fi

Tags: networking, wireless, lan, upnp

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 Mate. I use `gupnp-av-cp` from `gupnp-tools` package. It controls smart  tvs via LAN. It works OK on Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier versions.

It detects Sony Bravia on LAN but fails to set volume, etc. via `gupnp-av-cp` gui.

I found the following warning in `~/.xsession-errors`:

```
 ** (gupnp-av-cp:390810): WARNING **: 19:58:41.447: Failed to get sink protocol info from media renderer 'uuid:00000000-0000-1010-8000-F0BF97C2CB09':Forbidden
```

[image]

I noticed that `gupnp-av-cp` process opens `sh` then `pxgsettings` process.

```
Security Context  unconfined
Command Line  /fusr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy/0.4.17/pxgsettings org.gnome.system.proxy org.gnome.system.proxy.http org.gnome.system.proxy-https org.gnome.system.proxy.ftp org.gnome.system.proxy.socks

Waiting Channel  do_poll.constprop.0
ControlGroup  /fuserslice/user-1000.slice/session-c3.scope ()
```

What might be the problem?

**EDIT:**

I filed a bug report on launchpad :
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gupnp-tools/+bug/1993641

**EDIT2:**

Problem seems to be with system wide.

I used to play videos with chrome app `vget cast` but it also fails to play videos.

[image]

Another python app [nanodlna](https://github.com/goblin/nanodlna) which sends video to play in smart tv also fails

**EDIT3:**

But sending soap line manually with `curl` works:

```
curl -X POST -d '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" s:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><s:Body><u:X_SendIRCC xmlns:u="urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1"><IRCCCode>AAAAAQAAAAEAAAATAw==</IRCCCode></u:X_SendIRCC></s:Body></s:Envelope>' http://192.168.1.101/IRCC#volume-down
```

Comment: You have confirmed with the maker of the app that 22.04 mate is supported?

Comment: @David I installed it from official Ubuntu repositories. It should be supported by the maintainer.

Comment: Yes I suggested you ask them.